# Select em outra tabela MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Alguma dica de como posso selecionar todos os clientes de um determinado usuário?  Não estou entendendo muito a logica do como devo fazer a *query*.

[image: MySQL Table]

Comment: Acho que o que você está querendo é algo como `select * from clients where user_id = id_do_seu_usuario`. É relativamente simples

Comment: Legal cara, fiz do jeito que você falou peguei o id do User logado na sessão e joguei na query, retornou o resultado desejado, achei que seria mais complexo e necessário o uso de joins.. VLW!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para trazer somente os dados do cliente, baseado em um ID de usuário (já que você tem a referência de usuário user_id na tabela de clientes), da pra fazer assim:

```
SELECT * FROM clients
WHERE user_id = 123456
```

Mas se quiser trazer os dados de clientes E os dados de usuarios, adiciona o join na consulta.

```
SELECT * FROM clients
JOIN users ON users.id = clients.user_id
WHERE clients.user_id = 123456
```

Answer (score 2):

Fazendo a junção você terá a relação de todos os nomes da tabela clients que constam da tabela users.

```
SELECT clients.name 
FROM users INNER JOIN clients 
ON (users.id = clients.user_id)
```

Se quiser trazer todas as colunas, basta substituir name por *

```
SELECT clients.* 
FROM users INNER JOIN clients 
ON (users.id = clients.user_id)
```